# Make a USB drive read only

Tags: usb, firmware, read-only, write-protect

I have a 1.5TB USB drive with many important files that I want to give to a friend (they have Windows7) for reading only purposes. [thumbscrew](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/thumbscrew-software-usb-write-blocker) appears to flip a registry switch but it seems to be on the local pc only.

**UPDATE:**

Are you aware of any USB drives that have such functionality built into their firmware?

Comment: As the posters below have stated; locking would either need to be hardware (like a switch on the USB) or done on the local machine.
You could always mark your files as read only on the USB (right click-->Properties). Of course they could always un-mark the files from read-only and do whatever they like with them but the question is, will they?

Comment: I've often wished my hard drive enclosure had a readonly switch like some USB flash drives do.  That would make it much less unsettling to plug it into a friend's Windows machine.

Comment: Is is possible to format a pendrive using NTFS and then do it read-only with permissions? If a friend uses Linux, will the read-only protection fail?

Comment: Related: [How to physically damage a USB stick, SD card, or SDXC card to permanently make it read only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1609274)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about checking the "Read-only" box in the main folder's Properties and then applying to all subfolders?

Comment: So far this is the only solution that will work on any computer and os.

Comment: Note that this can be circumvented if you want to. At least on Linux (and probably on Windows) you can change the read-only state (or ignore it), if you have root/Admin on the machine the drive is connected to.

Comment: I would also add that things like Ghost or CloneDisk can trample all over this.

Answer (score 5):

My best option is use **DISKPART** form windows

**DISKPART**

**LIST DISK** (To check which flash drive listed as disk in windows)

**SELECT DISK 1** (It should be disk 1 if you have single hardisk attached to computer, disks naming starts from 0 but partition starts from 1)

**ATTRIBUTES DISK SET READONLY** [And its done ;-) ]

Comment: Can you revert it back to write mode after this?

Comment: Yea, use ATTRIBUTES DISK CLEAR READONLY and it'll clear the readonly flag on the disk.

Answer (score 2):

Any locking mechanism I'm aware of would be on your local machine.

Burn DVD's of the important stuff...  :)  That's about the only thing that will ensure they are read-only.

You might want to look at giving them a web interface via some apache file-sharing type of software.  That would give them some sort of web-nas view and you could more easily lock down the writes...

Comment: 1.5TB @ 8GB (dual-layer) = 192 DVDs... but they sure as hell would be read-only!

Comment: 192*15min/60=48 hours to burn them. I am not doing that for any friend of mine!

Comment: Whoops - read that drive size wrong.  I've added a web-nas idea to compensate.  :)

Comment: and did not count upload time for 1.5 Tb...:)

Comment: No web server unfortunately, has to be the drive itself.  Although this was an excellent suggestion!

Comment: I don't think that optical media (CD/DVDs) are a viable long term solution based on unfortunate experience, they just aren't as reliable as a hard drive or other solution.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished researching this exact thing and came up with the following companies that might be relevant:

NexCopy http://www.nexcopy.com/usb-secure-flash-drives/

SecuTech (Their UniKey DRIVE) http://www.esecutech.com/software-protection/unikey-family/unikey-family.html

Answer (score 1):

Addonics has a USB Read-Only portable cartridge system. simply insert your HDD 3.5" into it and it will be Read-Only (Write-Protected)

http://www.addonics.com/category/urd.php

Answer (score 0):

and did not count upload time for 1.5 Tb...:)

So As I understand, you want to provide your friend hole drive but your friend need part of them? Or you want to provide disk  "with many important files" to your friend to get him/her access to hole 1.5 Tb content? 
Its a life, a lot of examples around, are you 100% guarantee your friend will be "your friend" for all entire life? Nothing personal, But just want prevent wrong steps...
I do advise you to protect your info with something like that
http://www.password-protect-software.com/protect-folders.html
But its only my IMHO

Comment: It is just the accidental deletion I need protection from.

Comment: Ok, at this point just hide it:

Free methods:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-lock-or-hide-a-folder-a-file-or-a-drive-on-the-computer/

Software:

http://instantlock.net/

Comment: there's no real folder-protectors. All they can be BYPASSED.
The real folder-protection is an "archive" (compression:Store) and  password on it. Or alternative of that... But in this case if a part of the archive is damaged ... you know...

Answer (score 0):

Making a USB stick read only is done at the controller firmware level.  From what I know, there is no USB hard drive which has the feature for read-only at the firmware/controller level.  Like Jason said above, [Nexcopy](http://www.nexcopy.com/usb-duplicator/) has the ability to make read-only USB sticks, but not USB hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

This is a low-level hardware solution as opposed to a permissions-based solution.

On a Unix system, you can use `hdparm` to set SATA/IDE device parameters. One of those parameters is a read-only value.

Here is an example assuming your device is scsi device b (sdb):

Turn on read-only value (CAREFUL!)

```
hdparm -r1 /dev/sdb
```

Turn off read-only value

```
hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb
```

Read the current value

```
hdparm -r /dev/sdb
```

from `man hdparm`

> -r   Get/set device readonly flag (DANGEROUS to set)
>
> -R   Get/set device write-read-verify flag

Comment: Can this solution be reversed?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot ensure that your data will be only read, when you have to give disk to someone.

I'd advise you to make backup of your files, so that if something happens to data on your drive you'll always have a copy.